# Depth testing drawing issue on HTC devices

Tags: java, android, rendering, opengl-es-2.0, depth-buffer

I have a problem in which my opengl doesn't render properly on HTC devices.

I've tested it on a few other devices on which it renders properly.
is an example on a normal device:
[Here](http://i41.tinypic.com/11lrm7l.png) is an example on a normal device. And [here](http://i40.tinypic.com/33vn4f8.jpg) is an example with the HTC Desire and Desire S.

The problem when I added in

> GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

and goes again when I comment it out, but I can't just leave it out as then half my walls go invisible.

Is it possible it has something to do with [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209054/why-does-opengl-blending-not-work-on-htc-desire) Is there anything I can do? I can supply more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you've forgot to explicitly specify some stuff. Defaults differ between devices, and code which works on one GPU will fail on another one. Please make sure you've set all of these:

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth test
GLES20.glDepthMask(true); // write to z-buffer
GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL); // specify the way depth test works
```

When drawing geometry, always clean both color and depth buffers:

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear both color and z-buffer
```

And finally, ensure that you've properly initialized your OpenGL context and you do have depth buffer for used EGL config (`EGL_DEPTH_SIZE` is not 0). You can find a list of all available EGL configs for Desire S here: http://gfxbench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=gfx27&D=HTC+Desire+S&testgroup=egl

Comment: Brilliant thanks, I'd assumed that you only had to enable depth test and it would be the same across all devices. Quite stupid of me really.